# PGRouting Error Missing table?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, sql, pgrouting, shortest-path

I am trying to use `pgrouting` to find the shortest path in GeoServer. So I created new layer in sql view but its giving me error.

I created 3 table in database:

```
at_2po_4pgr = main table
at_2po_4pgr_noded = contains node network
at_2po_4pgr_noded_vertices_pgr= contains network topology [fields:]
```

and I wrote following sql statements in sql view in GeoServer

```
SELECT
 min(r.seq) AS seq,
 e.old_id AS id,
 e.name,
 sum(e.distance) AS distance,
ST_Collect(e.the_geom) AS geom 
 FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id,source,target,distance AS cost FROM at_2po_4pgr_noded',%source%,%target%,false) AS r,at_2po_4pgr_noded AS e 
 WHERE r.at_2po_4pgr=e.id 
GROUP BY e.old_id,e.name
```

but it shows this error:

```
Failed to create SQL view: ERROR: column r.at_2po_4pgr does not exist Position: 270
```

Answer (score 1):

As written, `r` is a table - the output from the pgr_dikstra function, and `at_2po_4pgr` is your main table.

The join between `at_2po_4pgr_noded` (aliased as `e`) and `r` must be done on the `id` column, not on the table name.

Try

```
 SELECT ...  
 FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id,source,target,distance AS cost FROM at_2po_4pgr_noded',%source%,%target%,false) AS r,at_2po_4pgr_noded AS e  
 WHERE r.id=e.id -- <**********
```